# kie-dmn-signavio-7.37.0.Final - unable to execute a DMN decision model that contains multi instance decision and zip function

Tags: drools, dmn

I am executing a DMN based decision model that got extracted from signavio tool. The model contains zip function as well as MID. see below the sample of my decision table

```
<decision name="collateOrder" id="id-85c7398c9bc186c1e2396c4625ebbcc1" label="Collate Order" sigExt:shapeId="sid-C47674E0-8CDE-4A4A-84E8-3DD179DCF72C" sigExt:diagramId="8462cb232d98419493d4ef846516a070">
    <extensionElements/>
    <variable typeRef="sig:collateOrder" name="collateOrder" id="id-85c7398c9bc186c1e2396c4625ebbcc1_variable"/>
    <informationRequirement>
        <requiredInput href="#id-a47f651b80111a121d93cf07939b20dc"/>
    </informationRequirement>
    <literalExpression expressionLanguage="http://www.omg.org/spec/FEEL/20140401">
        <text>zip(["Item Name", "Item Price", "Item Quantity"], [order.itemName, order.price, order.quantity])</text>
    </literalExpression>
</decision>
```

I am using kie-dmn-signavio-7.37.0.Final.jar

on my java code, i pass argument like below

```
    DMNContext context = runtime.newContext();
    List fieldList = Arrays.asList("itemName", "price", "quantity");
    List<String> itemList = Arrays.asList("item1", "item2", "item3");
    List<BigDecimal> priceList = Arrays.asList(new BigDecimal(1000), new BigDecimal(200), new BigDecimal(3000));
    List<Integer> qtyList = Arrays.asList(100, 20, 300);
    List<List> valLiist = Arrays.asList(itemList, priceList, qtyList);
    List<List> finalList = Arrays.asList(fieldList, valLiist);
    context.set("order", finalList);
    DMNResult evaluateAll = runtime.evaluateAll(model0, context);
```

When i run my code, i am getting below error message
23:52:26.989 [main] ERROR org.kie.dmn.core.ast.DMNLiteralExpressionEvaluator - FEEL ERROR while evaluating literal expression 'zip(["Item Name", "Item Price", "Item Quantity"], ... [string clipped after 50 chars, total length is 96]': The parameter 'values', in function zip(), values must be a list of the same size as of attributes.

Not sure what is wrong on my input.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> see below the sample of my decision table

The sample snippet you provided actually is not a decision table but a FEEL literal expression :)

Regardless, I believe you are not using the Signavio's extended zip function correctly.

> zip(attributes, values1, ..., valuesN) Assembles a list of objects out of a list of attributes and multiple lists of values.

### Problem 1: fix correct usage of extended zip function

So in your case because you have attributes of size 3, you must supply 3 lists of N elements each.

In other words:

```
zip(["Item Name", "Item Price", "Item Quantity"],
    list of names,
    list of prices,
    list of qtys)
```

that for your DMN model it would be like saying:

```
zip(["Item Name", "Item Price", "Item Quantity"], order.itemName, order.price, order.quantity)
```

### Problem 2: fix correct supply of Java composite object

Also on your Java input you are not supplying the expected composite object, `order` is a list of complex object each having `"itemName", "price", "quantity"` attributes.

### Conclusions

Once I fixed those issues it works fine, I will include sample DMN and Java test snippet below.

Important. However it is a bit difficult to understand the use-case based on the elements provided in the original question, so you might want to revise if the `zip()` function use is needed at all, and just make use of DMN Standard functionalities.

---

Full fixed example DMN model:

```xml
<dmn:definitions xmlns:dmn="http://www.omg.org/spec/DMN/20180521/MODEL/" xmlns="https://kiegroup.org/dmn/_CEDFCB71-C301-4AF7-8438-3C906965946C" xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DMN/20180521/DI/" xmlns:kie="http://www.drools.org/kie/dmn/1.2" xmlns:dmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DMN/20180521/DMNDI/" xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DMN/20180521/DC/" xmlns:feel="http://www.omg.org/spec/DMN/20180521/FEEL/" id="_C606E3BA-A1A8-4D0A-A1E8-AE404B568CC0" name="9B64A25E-4853-4D7B-B8FE-33E98234AE51" typeLanguage="http://www.omg.org/spec/DMN/20180521/FEEL/" namespace="https://kiegroup.org/dmn/_CEDFCB71-C301-4AF7-8438-3C906965946C">
  <dmn:extensionElements/>
  <dmn:inputData id="_AFE2999A-D71C-4C4B-B1D7-CC1DB6650FC1" name="order">
    <dmn:extensionElements/>
    <dmn:variable id="_F69956F1-49DA-46C8-A0DA-9E84AF18D0B2" name="order"/>
  </dmn:inputData>
  <dmn:decision id="_48E05B28-5BEB-457E-BCDB-16023684FA3E" name="collateOrder">
    <dmn:extensionElements/>
    <dmn:variable id="_69BECEE8-924A-411C-84EE-769432DF5C22" name="collateOrder"/>
    <dmn:informationRequirement id="_4533C1C4-E3F3-4557-ABE1-A2264908875F">
      <dmn:requiredInput href="#_AFE2999A-D71C-4C4B-B1D7-CC1DB6650FC1"/>
    </dmn:informationRequirement>
    <dmn:literalExpression id="_F029607F-4296-4ADE-B669-AC6FD5AB91FD">
      <dmn:text>zip(["Item Name", "Item Price", "Item Quantity"], order.itemName, order.price, order.quantity)</dmn:text>
    </dmn:literalExpression>
  </dmn:decision>
</dmn:definitions>
```

test snippet:

```java
        DMNContext context = runtime.newContext();
        Map<String, Object> item1 = new HashMap<>();
        item1.put("itemName", "item1");
        item1.put("price", new BigDecimal(1000));
        item1.put("quantity", 100);
        Map<String, Object> item2 = new HashMap<>();
        item2.put("itemName", "item2");
        item2.put("price", new BigDecimal(200));
        item2.put("quantity", 20);
        Map<String, Object> item3 = new HashMap<>();
        item3.put("itemName", "item3");
        item3.put("price", new BigDecimal(3000));
        item3.put("quantity", 300);
        context.set("order", Arrays.asList(item1, item2, item3));
        DMNResult evaluateAll = runtime.evaluateAll(model0, context);
        System.out.println(evaluateAll.getContext());
```

results:

```java
{
    order: [{itemName=item1, quantity=100, price=1000}, {itemName=item2, quantity=20, price=200}, {itemName=item3, quantity=300, price=3000}]
    collateOrder: [{Item Name=item1, Item Quantity=100, Item Price=1000}, {Item Name=item2, Item Quantity=20, Item Price=200}, {Item Name=item3, Item Quantity=300, Item Price=3000}]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response

Comment: @JavaExplorer if it helps solving, please don't forget to mark as Answered

Comment: My apologies. I am new to this blog. my response has gone above to your answer. I am using zip function to consolidate multiple values.

Comment: @JavaExplorer that sounds like a different problem. Your original question was about error with `zip` function which I believe my answer solved for you. Please mark this as accepted if the case. And for your new problem, feel free to post a new StackOverflow question or you can also ask on the Drools-usage forum

Comment: I agree - your solution has resolved my original query. Thank you so much for your time on this.

Comment: @JavaExplorer happy to try look further into the other issue, once is properly posted as a new question or on the forum, let me know!

Comment: thank you. I got 2 different zip & MID use case that i am struggling to run it thru java. Here is the first one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62033195/dmn-decision-model-that-zip-inputs-with-mid

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response. Below is complete model which i able to run it thru simulator in signavio

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <definitions namespace="http://www.signavio.com/dmn/1.1/diagram/8462cb232d98419493d4ef846516a070.xml" exporterVersion="13.3.2" name="MID Example" id="id-f1fe73d348e342d2a6f0435b38ce14e6" sigExt:revisionId="9f563b074ba844d4b9d1fcd6bead7580" sigExt:revisionNumber="1" xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/DMN/20151101/dmn.xsd" xmlns:sig="http://www.signavio.com/dmn/1.1/diagram/8462cb232d98419493d4ef846516a070.xml" xmlns:sigExt="http://www.signavio.com/schema/dmn/1.1/" xmlns:feel="http://www.omg.org/spec/FEEL/20140401">
<extensionElements/>
<itemDefinition isCollection="false" name="calculatePriceAfterDiscount" id="id-f8c81ba73d98a8a51216f4583ed31dc9" label="Calculate Price After Discount">
    <typeRef>feel:number</typeRef>
</itemDefinition>
<itemDefinition isCollection="false" name="calculatePrice" id="id-e13d8570789c69dec9515bd8b9159f2d" label="Calculate Price ">
    <typeRef>feel:number</typeRef>
</itemDefinition>
<itemDefinition isCollection="false" name="determineDiscount" id="id-99dded75dc910f4c4b3e2f1d3471cd10" label="Determine Discount %">
    <typeRef>feel:number</typeRef>
</itemDefinition>
<itemDefinition isCollection="false" name="discount" id="id-e41b37d9d6d86919af6290e062ee6bbe" label="Discount">
    <typeRef>feel:number</typeRef>
</itemDefinition>
<itemDefinition isCollection="false" name="collateOrder2" id="id-a4abe03e2f888a7830f15614f50bc45a" label="Collate Order">
    <itemComponent isCollection="false" name="itemName" id="id-a4abe03e2f888a7830f15614f50bc45a-relation-ItemName" label="Item Name" sigExt:slotId="Item Name">
        <typeRef>feel:string</typeRef>
    </itemComponent>
    <itemComponent isCollection="false" name="itemPrice" id="id-a4abe03e2f888a7830f15614f50bc45a-relation-ItemPrice" label="Item Price" sigExt:slotId="Item Price">
        <typeRef>feel:number</typeRef>
    </itemComponent>
    <itemComponent isCollection="false" name="itemQuantity" id="id-a4abe03e2f888a7830f15614f50bc45a-relation-ItemQuantity" label="Item Quantity" sigExt:slotId="Item Quantity">
        <typeRef>feel:number</typeRef>
    </itemComponent>
</itemDefinition>
<itemDefinition isCollection="false" name="calculateTotalPrice" id="id-753285786a1cec905c139529a673b0fe" label="Calculate Total Price">
    <typeRef>feel:number</typeRef>
</itemDefinition>
<itemDefinition isCollection="false" name="itemPrice" id="id-1a281dc9cb860f8ffd0c4cef9485f6a0" label="Item Price ">
    <typeRef>feel:number</typeRef>
</itemDefinition>
<itemDefinition isCollection="true" name="collateOrder" id="id-8cbabc9f5673d5e84b524b68155dcb45" label="Collate Order">
    <itemComponent isCollection="false" name="itemName" id="id-8cbabc9f5673d5e84b524b68155dcb45-relation-ItemName" label="Item Name" sigExt:slotId="Item Name">
        <typeRef>feel:string</typeRef>
    </itemComponent>
    <itemComponent isCollection="false" name="itemPrice" id="id-8cbabc9f5673d5e84b524b68155dcb45-relation-ItemPrice" label="Item Price" sigExt:slotId="Item Price">
        <typeRef>feel:number</typeRef>
    </itemComponent>
    <itemComponent isCollection="false" name="itemQuantity" id="id-8cbabc9f5673d5e84b524b68155dcb45-relation-ItemQuantity" label="Item Quantity" sigExt:slotId="Item Quantity">
        <typeRef>feel:number</typeRef>
    </itemComponent>
</itemDefinition>
<itemDefinition isCollection="false" name="order" id="id-4cc8046b78214ad11657d5b06436db21" label="Order ">
    <itemComponent isCollection="true" name="price" id="id-4cc8046b78214ad11657d5b06436db21-relation-0" label="Price" sigExt:slotId="0">
        <typeRef>feel:number</typeRef>
    </itemComponent>
    <itemComponent isCollection="true" name="quantity" id="id-4cc8046b78214ad11657d5b06436db21-relation-1" label="Quantity" sigExt:slotId="1">
        <typeRef>feel:number</typeRef>
    </itemComponent>
    <itemComponent isCollection="true" name="itemName" id="id-4cc8046b78214ad11657d5b06436db21-relation-2" label="Item Name" sigExt:slotId="2">
        <typeRef>feel:string</typeRef>
    </itemComponent>
</itemDefinition>
<inputData name="collateOrder_iterator" id="id-4835f35ebd354e9d65c600afb02d9d3c" label="Collate Order" sigExt:shapeId="sid-139D76F2-2029-4058-B488-9472C5BBEBC6" sigExt:diagramId="8462cb232d98419493d4ef846516a070">
    <extensionElements/>
    <variable typeRef="sig:collateOrder2" name="collateOrder_iterator" id="id-4835f35ebd354e9d65c600afb02d9d3c_variable"/>
</inputData>
<inputData name="order" id="id-a47f651b80111a121d93cf07939b20dc" label="Order " sigExt:shapeId="sid-8352CBF9-98EA-4018-9EAC-F17A5F936551" sigExt:diagramId="8462cb232d98419493d4ef846516a070">
    <extensionElements/>
    <variable typeRef="sig:order" name="order" id="id-a47f651b80111a121d93cf07939b20dc_variable"/>
</inputData>
<decision name="calculatePriceAfterDiscount" id="id-567eb0877fe31a6d84a53c3917e4eee0" label="Calculate Price After Discount" sigExt:shapeId="sid-5F8D6179-84FD-47B9-BA88-0E3CB4305014" sigExt:diagramId="8462cb232d98419493d4ef846516a070">
    <extensionElements/>
    <variable typeRef="sig:calculatePriceAfterDiscount" name="calculatePriceAfterDiscount" id="id-567eb0877fe31a6d84a53c3917e4eee0_variable"/>
    <informationRequirement>
        <requiredDecision href="#id-bc493858d94a5f245b95febc081cb0c7"/>
    </informationRequirement>
    <informationRequirement>
        <requiredDecision href="#id-d045696f950f3769011d375f7a1afd78"/>
    </informationRequirement>
    <literalExpression expressionLanguage="http://www.omg.org/spec/FEEL/20140401">
        <text>(calculatePrice-((determineDiscount/100)*calculatePrice))</text>
    </literalExpression>
</decision>
<decision name="calculateTotalPrice" id="id-be5d8465feb66b570cf75aeee595bf21" label="Calculate Total Price" sigExt:shapeId="sid-EA841422-3493-491C-9CE6-59F5EA9CE261" sigExt:diagramId="8462cb232d98419493d4ef846516a070">
    <extensionElements/>
    <variable typeRef="sig:calculateTotalPrice" name="calculateTotalPrice" id="id-be5d8465feb66b570cf75aeee595bf21_variable"/>
    <informationRequirement>
        <requiredInput href="#id-4835f35ebd354e9d65c600afb02d9d3c"/>
    </informationRequirement>
    <decisionTable hitPolicy="UNIQUE">
        <input id="id-137491756d969eac658224df41ae34d3" label="Price">
            <inputExpression>
                <text>collateOrder_iterator.itemPrice</text>
            </inputExpression>
        </input>
        <input id="id-cad45b775d319f14f2cc11d5d3b758fd" label="Quantity">
            <inputExpression>
                <text>collateOrder_iterator.itemQuantity</text>
            </inputExpression>
        </input>
        <output name="calculateTotalPrice" typeRef="sig:itemPrice" id="id-99e0fdb7f0d56dbc7bb88ae025be147c" label="Calculate Total Price"/>
        <rule id="id-2fff85d2331aa1e369d698392addb0a8">
            <description>string(-)</description>
            <inputEntry>
                <text>not(null)</text>
            </inputEntry>
            <inputEntry>
                <text>not(null)</text>
            </inputEntry>
            <outputEntry>
                <text>(collateOrder_iterator.itemPrice*collateOrder_iterator.itemQuantity)</text>
            </outputEntry>
        </rule>
    </decisionTable>
</decision>
<decision name="determineDiscount" id="id-bc493858d94a5f245b95febc081cb0c7" label="Determine Discount %" sigExt:shapeId="sid-6824DDAF-771A-4773-973E-1477F70EC90B" sigExt:diagramId="8462cb232d98419493d4ef846516a070">
    <extensionElements/>
    <variable typeRef="sig:determineDiscount" name="determineDiscount" id="id-bc493858d94a5f245b95febc081cb0c7_variable"/>
    <informationRequirement>
        <requiredDecision href="#id-d045696f950f3769011d375f7a1afd78"/>
    </informationRequirement>
    <decisionTable hitPolicy="UNIQUE">
        <input id="id-8a61ecb31c82e81d0b067a63f8a10b25" label="Calculate Price ">
            <inputExpression>
                <text>calculatePrice</text>
            </inputExpression>
        </input>
        <output name="determineDiscount" typeRef="sig:discount" id="id-cd2468e782346733c82b544eae541110" label="Determine Discount %"/>
        <rule id="id-8ce83be6aaf7113a136fadb09f2de83b">
            <description>string(-)</description>
            <inputEntry>
                <text>[0..500)</text>
            </inputEntry>
            <outputEntry>
                <text>1</text>
            </outputEntry>
        </rule>
        <rule id="id-ba19200060db4a933658db98400f5019">
            <description>string(-)</description>
            <inputEntry>
                <text>[500..1000)</text>
            </inputEntry>
            <outputEntry>
                <text>5</text>
            </outputEntry>
        </rule>
        <rule id="id-23a4b91a413530151413d2230f41e010">
            <description>string(-)</description>
            <inputEntry>
                <text>[1000..5000)</text>
            </inputEntry>
            <outputEntry>
                <text>10</text>
            </outputEntry>
        </rule>
        <rule id="id-9b4dbf30626d219d5e7937c1322b33fe">
            <description>string(-)</description>
            <inputEntry>
                <text>[5000..10000]</text>
            </inputEntry>
            <outputEntry>
                <text>20</text>
            </outputEntry>
        </rule>
        <rule id="id-37139385183b4a6ee481738ccccc02f4">
            <description>string(-)</description>
            <inputEntry>
                <text>&gt; 10000</text>
            </inputEntry>
            <outputEntry>
                <text>25</text>
            </outputEntry>
        </rule>
        <rule id="id-7d86977d4be287545686b09f982b55a9">
            <description>string(-)</description>
            <inputEntry>
                <text>&lt; 0</text>
            </inputEntry>
            <outputEntry>
                <text>0</text>
            </outputEntry>
        </rule>
    </decisionTable>
</decision>
<decision name="calculatePrice" id="id-d045696f950f3769011d375f7a1afd78" label="Calculate Price " sigExt:shapeId="sid-E3A6C7E0-BEE6-47C9-97EC-1C5A95EE2DB4" sigExt:diagramId="8462cb232d98419493d4ef846516a070">
    <extensionElements>
        <sigExt:MultiInstanceDecisionLogic>
            <sigExt:iterationExpression>collateOrder</sigExt:iterationExpression>
            <sigExt:iteratorShapeId>id-4835f35ebd354e9d65c600afb02d9d3c</sigExt:iteratorShapeId>
            <sigExt:aggregationFunction>SUM</sigExt:aggregationFunction>
            <sigExt:topLevelDecisionId>id-be5d8465feb66b570cf75aeee595bf21</sigExt:topLevelDecisionId>
        </sigExt:MultiInstanceDecisionLogic>
    </extensionElements>
    <variable typeRef="sig:calculatePrice" name="calculatePrice" id="id-d045696f950f3769011d375f7a1afd78_variable"/>
    <informationRequirement>
        <requiredDecision href="#id-85c7398c9bc186c1e2396c4625ebbcc1"/>
    </informationRequirement>
</decision>
<decision name="collateOrder" id="id-85c7398c9bc186c1e2396c4625ebbcc1" label="Collate Order" sigExt:shapeId="sid-C47674E0-8CDE-4A4A-84E8-3DD179DCF72C" sigExt:diagramId="8462cb232d98419493d4ef846516a070">
    <extensionElements/>
    <variable typeRef="sig:collateOrder" name="collateOrder" id="id-85c7398c9bc186c1e2396c4625ebbcc1_variable"/>
    <informationRequirement>
        <requiredInput href="#id-a47f651b80111a121d93cf07939b20dc"/>
    </informationRequirement>
    <literalExpression expressionLanguage="http://www.omg.org/spec/FEEL/20140401">
        <text>zip(["Item Name", "Item Price", "Item Quantity"], order.itemName, order.price, order.quantity)</text>
    </literalExpression>
</decision>
```

'

I made changes to zip function as per what you said. When i run my java code,it says

15:24:39.930 [main] ERROR org.kie.dmn.feel.runtime.functions.DTInvokerFunction - Error invoking decision table 'determineDiscount': ClassCastException
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class java.math.BigDecimal (java.util.ArrayList and java.math.BigDecimal are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

Appreciate any pointers