# DMN decision model that zip inputs with MID

Tags: drools, dmn

I have below DMN model that zips input and calculate discount. I am able to run it thru simulator in signavio.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<definitions namespace="http://www.signavio.com/dmn/1.1/diagram/8462cb232d98419493d4ef846516a070.xml" exporterVersion="13.3.2" name="MID Example" id="id-f1fe73d348e342d2a6f0435b38ce14e6" sigExt:revisionId="9f563b074ba844d4b9d1fcd6bead7580" sigExt:revisionNumber="1" xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/DMN/20151101/dmn.xsd" xmlns:sig="http://www.signavio.com/dmn/1.1/diagram/8462cb232d98419493d4ef846516a070.xml" xmlns:sigExt="http://www.signavio.com/schema/dmn/1.1/" xmlns:feel="http://www.omg.org/spec/FEEL/20140401">
<extensionElements/>
<itemDefinition isCollection="false" name="calculatePriceAfterDiscount" id="id-f8c81ba73d98a8a51216f4583ed31dc9" label="Calculate Price After Discount">
    <typeRef>feel:number</typeRef>
</itemDefinition>
<itemDefinition isCollection="false" name="calculatePrice" id="id-e13d8570789c69dec9515bd8b9159f2d" label="Calculate Price ">
    <typeRef>feel:number</typeRef>
</itemDefinition>
<itemDefinition isCollection="false" name="determineDiscount" id="id-99dded75dc910f4c4b3e2f1d3471cd10" label="Determine Discount %">
    <typeRef>feel:number</typeRef>
</itemDefinition>
<itemDefinition isCollection="false" name="discount" id="id-e41b37d9d6d86919af6290e062ee6bbe" label="Discount">
    <typeRef>feel:number</typeRef>
</itemDefinition>
<itemDefinition isCollection="false" name="collateOrder2" id="id-a4abe03e2f888a7830f15614f50bc45a" label="Collate Order">
    <itemComponent isCollection="false" name="itemName" id="id-a4abe03e2f888a7830f15614f50bc45a-relation-ItemName" label="Item Name" sigExt:slotId="Item Name">
        <typeRef>feel:string</typeRef>
    </itemComponent>
    <itemComponent isCollection="false" name="itemPrice" id="id-a4abe03e2f888a7830f15614f50bc45a-relation-ItemPrice" label="Item Price" sigExt:slotId="Item Price">
        <typeRef>feel:number</typeRef>
    </itemComponent>
    <itemComponent isCollection="false" name="itemQuantity" id="id-a4abe03e2f888a7830f15614f50bc45a-relation-ItemQuantity" label="Item Quantity" sigExt:slotId="Item Quantity">
        <typeRef>feel:number</typeRef>
    </itemComponent>
</itemDefinition>
<itemDefinition isCollection="false" name="calculateTotalPrice" id="id-753285786a1cec905c139529a673b0fe" label="Calculate Total Price">
    <typeRef>feel:number</typeRef>
</itemDefinition>
<itemDefinition isCollection="false" name="itemPrice" id="id-1a281dc9cb860f8ffd0c4cef9485f6a0" label="Item Price ">
    <typeRef>feel:number</typeRef>
</itemDefinition>
<itemDefinition isCollection="true" name="collateOrder" id="id-8cbabc9f5673d5e84b524b68155dcb45" label="Collate Order">
    <itemComponent isCollection="false" name="itemName" id="id-8cbabc9f5673d5e84b524b68155dcb45-relation-ItemName" label="Item Name" sigExt:slotId="Item Name">
        <typeRef>feel:string</typeRef>
    </itemComponent>
    <itemComponent isCollection="false" name="itemPrice" id="id-8cbabc9f5673d5e84b524b68155dcb45-relation-ItemPrice" label="Item Price" sigExt:slotId="Item Price">
        <typeRef>feel:number</typeRef>
    </itemComponent>
    <itemComponent isCollection="false" name="itemQuantity" id="id-8cbabc9f5673d5e84b524b68155dcb45-relation-ItemQuantity" label="Item Quantity" sigExt:slotId="Item Quantity">
        <typeRef>feel:number</typeRef>
    </itemComponent>
</itemDefinition>
<itemDefinition isCollection="false" name="order" id="id-4cc8046b78214ad11657d5b06436db21" label="Order ">
    <itemComponent isCollection="true" name="price" id="id-4cc8046b78214ad11657d5b06436db21-relation-0" label="Price" sigExt:slotId="0">
        <typeRef>feel:number</typeRef>
    </itemComponent>
    <itemComponent isCollection="true" name="quantity" id="id-4cc8046b78214ad11657d5b06436db21-relation-1" label="Quantity" sigExt:slotId="1">
        <typeRef>feel:number</typeRef>
    </itemComponent>
    <itemComponent isCollection="true" name="itemName" id="id-4cc8046b78214ad11657d5b06436db21-relation-2" label="Item Name" sigExt:slotId="2">
        <typeRef>feel:string</typeRef>
    </itemComponent>
</itemDefinition>
<inputData name="collateOrder_iterator" id="id-4835f35ebd354e9d65c600afb02d9d3c" label="Collate Order" sigExt:shapeId="sid-139D76F2-2029-4058-B488-9472C5BBEBC6" sigExt:diagramId="8462cb232d98419493d4ef846516a070">
    <extensionElements/>
    <variable typeRef="sig:collateOrder2" name="collateOrder_iterator" id="id-4835f35ebd354e9d65c600afb02d9d3c_variable"/>
</inputData>
<inputData name="order" id="id-a47f651b80111a121d93cf07939b20dc" label="Order " sigExt:shapeId="sid-8352CBF9-98EA-4018-9EAC-F17A5F936551" sigExt:diagramId="8462cb232d98419493d4ef846516a070">
    <extensionElements/>
    <variable typeRef="sig:order" name="order" id="id-a47f651b80111a121d93cf07939b20dc_variable"/>
</inputData>
<decision name="calculatePriceAfterDiscount" id="id-567eb0877fe31a6d84a53c3917e4eee0" label="Calculate Price After Discount" sigExt:shapeId="sid-5F8D6179-84FD-47B9-BA88-0E3CB4305014" sigExt:diagramId="8462cb232d98419493d4ef846516a070">
    <extensionElements/>
    <variable typeRef="sig:calculatePriceAfterDiscount" name="calculatePriceAfterDiscount" id="id-567eb0877fe31a6d84a53c3917e4eee0_variable"/>
    <informationRequirement>
        <requiredDecision href="#id-bc493858d94a5f245b95febc081cb0c7"/>
    </informationRequirement>
    <informationRequirement>
        <requiredDecision href="#id-d045696f950f3769011d375f7a1afd78"/>
    </informationRequirement>
    <literalExpression expressionLanguage="http://www.omg.org/spec/FEEL/20140401">
        <text>(calculatePrice-((determineDiscount/100)*calculatePrice))</text>
    </literalExpression>
</decision>
<decision name="calculateTotalPrice" id="id-be5d8465feb66b570cf75aeee595bf21" label="Calculate Total Price" sigExt:shapeId="sid-EA841422-3493-491C-9CE6-59F5EA9CE261" sigExt:diagramId="8462cb232d98419493d4ef846516a070">
    <extensionElements/>
    <variable typeRef="sig:calculateTotalPrice" name="calculateTotalPrice" id="id-be5d8465feb66b570cf75aeee595bf21_variable"/>
    <informationRequirement>
        <requiredInput href="#id-4835f35ebd354e9d65c600afb02d9d3c"/>
    </informationRequirement>
    <decisionTable hitPolicy="UNIQUE">
        <input id="id-137491756d969eac658224df41ae34d3" label="Price">
            <inputExpression>
                <text>collateOrder_iterator.itemPrice</text>
            </inputExpression>
        </input>
        <input id="id-cad45b775d319f14f2cc11d5d3b758fd" label="Quantity">
            <inputExpression>
                <text>collateOrder_iterator.itemQuantity</text>
            </inputExpression>
        </input>
        <output name="calculateTotalPrice" typeRef="sig:itemPrice" id="id-99e0fdb7f0d56dbc7bb88ae025be147c" label="Calculate Total Price"/>
        <rule id="id-2fff85d2331aa1e369d698392addb0a8">
            <description>string(-)</description>
            <inputEntry>
                <text>not(null)</text>
            </inputEntry>
            <inputEntry>
                <text>not(null)</text>
            </inputEntry>
            <outputEntry>
                <text>(collateOrder_iterator.itemPrice*collateOrder_iterator.itemQuantity)</text>
            </outputEntry>
        </rule>
    </decisionTable>
</decision>
<decision name="determineDiscount" id="id-bc493858d94a5f245b95febc081cb0c7" label="Determine Discount %" sigExt:shapeId="sid-6824DDAF-771A-4773-973E-1477F70EC90B" sigExt:diagramId="8462cb232d98419493d4ef846516a070">
    <extensionElements/>
    <variable typeRef="sig:determineDiscount" name="determineDiscount" id="id-bc493858d94a5f245b95febc081cb0c7_variable"/>
    <informationRequirement>
        <requiredDecision href="#id-d045696f950f3769011d375f7a1afd78"/>
    </informationRequirement>
    <decisionTable hitPolicy="UNIQUE">
        <input id="id-8a61ecb31c82e81d0b067a63f8a10b25" label="Calculate Price ">
            <inputExpression>
                <text>calculatePrice</text>
            </inputExpression>
        </input>
        <output name="determineDiscount" typeRef="sig:discount" id="id-cd2468e782346733c82b544eae541110" label="Determine Discount %"/>
        <rule id="id-8ce83be6aaf7113a136fadb09f2de83b">
            <description>string(-)</description>
            <inputEntry>
                <text>[0..500)</text>
            </inputEntry>
            <outputEntry>
                <text>1</text>
            </outputEntry>
        </rule>
        <rule id="id-ba19200060db4a933658db98400f5019">
            <description>string(-)</description>
            <inputEntry>
                <text>[500..1000)</text>
            </inputEntry>
            <outputEntry>
                <text>5</text>
            </outputEntry>
        </rule>
        <rule id="id-23a4b91a413530151413d2230f41e010">
            <description>string(-)</description>
            <inputEntry>
                <text>[1000..5000)</text>
            </inputEntry>
            <outputEntry>
                <text>10</text>
            </outputEntry>
        </rule>
        <rule id="id-9b4dbf30626d219d5e7937c1322b33fe">
            <description>string(-)</description>
            <inputEntry>
                <text>[5000..10000]</text>
            </inputEntry>
            <outputEntry>
                <text>20</text>
            </outputEntry>
        </rule>
        <rule id="id-37139385183b4a6ee481738ccccc02f4">
            <description>string(-)</description>
            <inputEntry>
                <text>&gt; 10000</text>
            </inputEntry>
            <outputEntry>
                <text>25</text>
            </outputEntry>
        </rule>
        <rule id="id-7d86977d4be287545686b09f982b55a9">
            <description>string(-)</description>
            <inputEntry>
                <text>&lt; 0</text>
            </inputEntry>
            <outputEntry>
                <text>0</text>
            </outputEntry>
        </rule>
    </decisionTable>
</decision>
<decision name="calculatePrice" id="id-d045696f950f3769011d375f7a1afd78" label="Calculate Price " sigExt:shapeId="sid-E3A6C7E0-BEE6-47C9-97EC-1C5A95EE2DB4" sigExt:diagramId="8462cb232d98419493d4ef846516a070">
    <extensionElements>
        <sigExt:MultiInstanceDecisionLogic>
            <sigExt:iterationExpression>collateOrder</sigExt:iterationExpression>
            <sigExt:iteratorShapeId>id-4835f35ebd354e9d65c600afb02d9d3c</sigExt:iteratorShapeId>
            <sigExt:aggregationFunction>SUM</sigExt:aggregationFunction>
            <sigExt:topLevelDecisionId>id-be5d8465feb66b570cf75aeee595bf21</sigExt:topLevelDecisionId>
        </sigExt:MultiInstanceDecisionLogic>
    </extensionElements>
    <variable typeRef="sig:calculatePrice" name="calculatePrice" id="id-d045696f950f3769011d375f7a1afd78_variable"/>
    <informationRequirement>
        <requiredDecision href="#id-85c7398c9bc186c1e2396c4625ebbcc1"/>
    </informationRequirement>
</decision>
<decision name="collateOrder" id="id-85c7398c9bc186c1e2396c4625ebbcc1" label="Collate Order" sigExt:shapeId="sid-C47674E0-8CDE-4A4A-84E8-3DD179DCF72C" sigExt:diagramId="8462cb232d98419493d4ef846516a070">
    <extensionElements/>
    <variable typeRef="sig:collateOrder" name="collateOrder" id="id-85c7398c9bc186c1e2396c4625ebbcc1_variable"/>
    <informationRequirement>
        <requiredInput href="#id-a47f651b80111a121d93cf07939b20dc"/>
    </informationRequirement>
    <literalExpression expressionLanguage="http://www.omg.org/spec/FEEL/20140401">
        <text>zip(["Item Name", "Item Price", "Item Quantity"], [order.itemName, order.price, order.quantity])</text>
    </literalExpression>
</decision>
```

I have tried to change the zip as below

zip(["Item Name", "Item Price", "Item Quantity"],order.itemName, order.price, order.quantity)

When i run it thru my java code, i am getting below error message

19:40:43.251 [main] ERROR org.kie.dmn.feel.runtime.functions.DTInvokerFunction - Error invoking decision table 'determineDiscount': ClassCastException
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class java.math.BigDecimal (java.util.ArrayList and java.math.BigDecimal are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

My java code will be like this

```
    final KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
    final KieFileSystem kfs = ks.newKieFileSystem();
    KieModuleModel kmm = ks.newKieModuleModel();
    kmm.setConfigurationProperty("org.kie.dmn.profiles.signavio", "org.kie.dmn.signavio.KieDMNSignavioProfile");
    kfs.writeKModuleXML(kmm.toXML());
    kfs.write(ks.getResources().newClassPathResource("MID Example (2).dmn", this.getClass()));
    KieBuilder kieBuilder = ks.newKieBuilder(kfs).buildAll();
    Results results = kieBuilder.getResults();
    logger.info("buildAll() completed.");
    results.getMessages(Message.Level.WARNING).forEach(e -> logger.warn("{}", e));
    final KieContainer kieContainer = ks.newKieContainer(ks.getRepository().getDefaultReleaseId());
    DMNRuntime runtime = kieContainer.newKieSession().getKieRuntime(DMNRuntime.class);
    DMNModel model0 = runtime.getModels().get(0);
    DMNContext context = runtime.newContext();
    Map<String, Object> item1 = new HashMap<>();
    item1.put("itemName", "item1");
    item1.put("price", 1000);
    item1.put("quantity", 100);
    Map<String, Object> item2 = new HashMap<>();
    item2.put("itemName", "item2");
    item2.put("price", 200);
    item2.put("quantity", 20);
    Map<String, Object> item3 = new HashMap<>();
    item3.put("itemName", "item3");
    item3.put("price", 3000);
    item3.put("quantity", 300);
    context.set("order", Arrays.asList(item1, item2, item3));
    DMNResult evaluateAll = runtime.evaluateAll(model0, context);
    evaluateAll.getMessages().forEach(System.out::println);
    List<DMNDecisionResult> decResutls = evaluateAll.getDecisionResults();
    printDecisionResults(decResutls);
```

Appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for providing all required assets/code to reproduce the issue in full.
I believe there are several problems which I will describe below, and provide a complete fixed/working example bottom.

## Problem: respecting the Order type definition.

Based on your full DMN model definition, the Order (input data node value) must be a singleton composite object of `"itemName", "price", "quantity"` properties; each of this property is a collection.

So the input should be something like:

```
    order: {
        itemName: [item1, item2, item3]
        quantity: [100, 20, 300]
        price: [1000, 200, 3000]
    }
```

## Problem: respecting the zip function consistent with Order type definition

Based on your full DMN model definition, the correct definition for the zip function shall be:

```
zip(["Item Name", "Item Price", "Item Quantity"], order.itemName, order.price, order.quantity)
```

as I assume what you want to do, based on the full DMN model definition, is transform the data into the following structure

```
collateOrder: [
   {
      Item Name=item1,
      Item Quantity=100,
      Item Price=1000
   },
   {
      Item Name=item2,
      Item Quantity=20,
      Item Price=200
   },
   {
      Item Name=item3,
      Item Quantity=300,
      Item Price=3000
   }
]
```

## Problem: MID aggregation function

I believe I found a bug in the Signavio extension implementation; thank you for reporting this will be investigated further.

However you can do the required business logic by using the much simpler standard DMN literal expression, without having to rely on any extension beyond what defined only in the DMN specification itself:

```
sum( for order in collateOrder return ( order.Item Price * order.Item Quantity ) )
```

this does not require any (Signavio) extension, and it's valid DMN.

---

To recap.

Java test code snippet:

```java
        DMNContext context = runtime.newContext();
        List<String> itemList = Arrays.asList("item1", "item2", "item3");
        List<BigDecimal> priceList = Arrays.asList(new BigDecimal(1000), new BigDecimal(200), new BigDecimal(3000));
        List<Integer> qtyList = Arrays.asList(100, 20, 300);
        Map<String, Object> order = new HashMap<>();
        order.put("itemName", itemList);
        order.put("price", priceList);
        order.put("quantity", qtyList);
        context.set("order", order);
        DMNResult evaluateAll = runtime.evaluateAll(model0, context);
```

fixed DMN model, without requiring any special extension:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<definitions namespace="http://www.signavio.com/dmn/1.1/diagram/8462cb232d98419493d4ef846516a070.xml" exporterVersion="13.3.2" name="MID Example" id="id-f1fe73d348e342d2a6f0435b38ce14e6" sigExt:revisionId="9f563b074ba844d4b9d1fcd6bead7580" sigExt:revisionNumber="1" xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/DMN/20151101/dmn.xsd" xmlns:sig="http://www.signavio.com/dmn/1.1/diagram/8462cb232d98419493d4ef846516a070.xml" xmlns:sigExt="http://www.signavio.com/schema/dmn/1.1/" xmlns:feel="http://www.omg.org/spec/FEEL/20140401">
<extensionElements/>
<itemDefinition isCollection="false" name="calculatePriceAfterDiscount" id="id-f8c81ba73d98a8a51216f4583ed31dc9" label="Calculate Price After Discount">
    <typeRef>feel:number</typeRef>
</itemDefinition>
<itemDefinition isCollection="false" name="calculatePrice" id="id-e13d8570789c69dec9515bd8b9159f2d" label="Calculate Price ">
    <typeRef>feel:number</typeRef>
</itemDefinition>
<itemDefinition isCollection="false" name="determineDiscount" id="id-99dded75dc910f4c4b3e2f1d3471cd10" label="Determine Discount %">
    <typeRef>feel:number</typeRef>
</itemDefinition>
<itemDefinition isCollection="false" name="discount" id="id-e41b37d9d6d86919af6290e062ee6bbe" label="Discount">
    <typeRef>feel:number</typeRef>
</itemDefinition>
<itemDefinition isCollection="false" name="collateOrder2" id="id-a4abe03e2f888a7830f15614f50bc45a" label="Collate Order">
    <itemComponent isCollection="false" name="itemName" id="id-a4abe03e2f888a7830f15614f50bc45a-relation-ItemName" label="Item Name" sigExt:slotId="Item Name">
        <typeRef>feel:string</typeRef>
    </itemComponent>
    <itemComponent isCollection="false" name="itemPrice" id="id-a4abe03e2f888a7830f15614f50bc45a-relation-ItemPrice" label="Item Price" sigExt:slotId="Item Price">
        <typeRef>feel:number</typeRef>
    </itemComponent>
    <itemComponent isCollection="false" name="itemQuantity" id="id-a4abe03e2f888a7830f15614f50bc45a-relation-ItemQuantity" label="Item Quantity" sigExt:slotId="Item Quantity">
        <typeRef>feel:number</typeRef>
    </itemComponent>
</itemDefinition>
<itemDefinition isCollection="false" name="calculateTotalPrice" id="id-753285786a1cec905c139529a673b0fe" label="Calculate Total Price">
    <typeRef>feel:number</typeRef>
</itemDefinition>
<itemDefinition isCollection="false" name="itemPrice" id="id-1a281dc9cb860f8ffd0c4cef9485f6a0" label="Item Price ">
    <typeRef>feel:number</typeRef>
</itemDefinition>
<itemDefinition isCollection="true" name="collateOrder" id="id-8cbabc9f5673d5e84b524b68155dcb45" label="Collate Order">
    <itemComponent isCollection="false" name="itemName" id="id-8cbabc9f5673d5e84b524b68155dcb45-relation-ItemName" label="Item Name" sigExt:slotId="Item Name">
        <typeRef>feel:string</typeRef>
    </itemComponent>
    <itemComponent isCollection="false" name="itemPrice" id="id-8cbabc9f5673d5e84b524b68155dcb45-relation-ItemPrice" label="Item Price" sigExt:slotId="Item Price">
        <typeRef>feel:number</typeRef>
    </itemComponent>
    <itemComponent isCollection="false" name="itemQuantity" id="id-8cbabc9f5673d5e84b524b68155dcb45-relation-ItemQuantity" label="Item Quantity" sigExt:slotId="Item Quantity">
        <typeRef>feel:number</typeRef>
    </itemComponent>
</itemDefinition>
<itemDefinition isCollection="false" name="order" id="id-4cc8046b78214ad11657d5b06436db21" label="Order ">
    <itemComponent isCollection="true" name="price" id="id-4cc8046b78214ad11657d5b06436db21-relation-0" label="Price" sigExt:slotId="0">
        <typeRef>feel:number</typeRef>
    </itemComponent>
    <itemComponent isCollection="true" name="quantity" id="id-4cc8046b78214ad11657d5b06436db21-relation-1" label="Quantity" sigExt:slotId="1">
        <typeRef>feel:number</typeRef>
    </itemComponent>
    <itemComponent isCollection="true" name="itemName" id="id-4cc8046b78214ad11657d5b06436db21-relation-2" label="Item Name" sigExt:slotId="2">
        <typeRef>feel:string</typeRef>
    </itemComponent>
</itemDefinition>
<inputData name="order" id="id-a47f651b80111a121d93cf07939b20dc" label="Order " sigExt:shapeId="sid-8352CBF9-98EA-4018-9EAC-F17A5F936551" sigExt:diagramId="8462cb232d98419493d4ef846516a070">
    <extensionElements/>
    <variable typeRef="sig:order" name="order" id="id-a47f651b80111a121d93cf07939b20dc_variable"/>
</inputData>
<decision name="calculatePriceAfterDiscount" id="id-567eb0877fe31a6d84a53c3917e4eee0" label="Calculate Price After Discount" sigExt:shapeId="sid-5F8D6179-84FD-47B9-BA88-0E3CB4305014" sigExt:diagramId="8462cb232d98419493d4ef846516a070">
    <extensionElements/>
    <variable typeRef="sig:calculatePriceAfterDiscount" name="calculatePriceAfterDiscount" id="id-567eb0877fe31a6d84a53c3917e4eee0_variable"/>
    <informationRequirement>
        <requiredDecision href="#id-bc493858d94a5f245b95febc081cb0c7"/>
    </informationRequirement>
    <informationRequirement>
        <requiredDecision href="#id-d045696f950f3769011d375f7a1afd78"/>
    </informationRequirement>
    <literalExpression expressionLanguage="http://www.omg.org/spec/FEEL/20140401">
        <text>(calculatePrice-((determineDiscount/100)*calculatePrice))</text>
    </literalExpression>
</decision>
<decision name="determineDiscount" id="id-bc493858d94a5f245b95febc081cb0c7" label="Determine Discount %" sigExt:shapeId="sid-6824DDAF-771A-4773-973E-1477F70EC90B" sigExt:diagramId="8462cb232d98419493d4ef846516a070">
    <extensionElements/>
    <variable typeRef="sig:determineDiscount" name="determineDiscount" id="id-bc493858d94a5f245b95febc081cb0c7_variable"/>
    <informationRequirement>
        <requiredDecision href="#id-d045696f950f3769011d375f7a1afd78"/>
    </informationRequirement>
    <decisionTable hitPolicy="UNIQUE">
        <input id="id-8a61ecb31c82e81d0b067a63f8a10b25" label="Calculate Price ">
            <inputExpression>
                <text>calculatePrice</text>
            </inputExpression>
        </input>
        <output name="determineDiscount" typeRef="sig:discount" id="id-cd2468e782346733c82b544eae541110" label="Determine Discount %"/>
        <rule id="id-8ce83be6aaf7113a136fadb09f2de83b">
            <description>string(-)</description>
            <inputEntry>
                <text>[0..500)</text>
            </inputEntry>
            <outputEntry>
                <text>1</text>
            </outputEntry>
        </rule>
        <rule id="id-ba19200060db4a933658db98400f5019">
            <description>string(-)</description>
            <inputEntry>
                <text>[500..1000)</text>
            </inputEntry>
            <outputEntry>
                <text>5</text>
            </outputEntry>
        </rule>
        <rule id="id-23a4b91a413530151413d2230f41e010">
            <description>string(-)</description>
            <inputEntry>
                <text>[1000..5000)</text>
            </inputEntry>
            <outputEntry>
                <text>10</text>
            </outputEntry>
        </rule>
        <rule id="id-9b4dbf30626d219d5e7937c1322b33fe">
            <description>string(-)</description>
            <inputEntry>
                <text>[5000..10000]</text>
            </inputEntry>
            <outputEntry>
                <text>20</text>
            </outputEntry>
        </rule>
        <rule id="id-37139385183b4a6ee481738ccccc02f4">
            <description>string(-)</description>
            <inputEntry>
                <text>&gt; 10000</text>
            </inputEntry>
            <outputEntry>
                <text>25</text>
            </outputEntry>
        </rule>
        <rule id="id-7d86977d4be287545686b09f982b55a9">
            <description>string(-)</description>
            <inputEntry>
                <text>&lt; 0</text>
            </inputEntry>
            <outputEntry>
                <text>0</text>
            </outputEntry>
        </rule>
    </decisionTable>
</decision>
<decision name="calculatePrice" id="id-d045696f950f3769011d375f7a1afd78" label="Calculate Price " sigExt:shapeId="sid-E3A6C7E0-BEE6-47C9-97EC-1C5A95EE2DB4" sigExt:diagramId="8462cb232d98419493d4ef846516a070">
    <literalExpression expressionLanguage="http://www.omg.org/spec/FEEL/20140401">
        <text>sum( for order in collateOrder return ( order.Item Price * order.Item Quantity ) )</text>
    </literalExpression>
    <variable typeRef="sig:calculatePrice" name="calculatePrice" id="id-d045696f950f3769011d375f7a1afd78_variable"/>
    <informationRequirement>
        <requiredDecision href="#id-85c7398c9bc186c1e2396c4625ebbcc1"/>
    </informationRequirement>
</decision>
<decision name="collateOrder" id="id-85c7398c9bc186c1e2396c4625ebbcc1" label="Collate Order" sigExt:shapeId="sid-C47674E0-8CDE-4A4A-84E8-3DD179DCF72C" sigExt:diagramId="8462cb232d98419493d4ef846516a070">
    <extensionElements/>
    <variable typeRef="sig:collateOrder" name="collateOrder" id="id-85c7398c9bc186c1e2396c4625ebbcc1_variable"/>
    <informationRequirement>
        <requiredInput href="#id-a47f651b80111a121d93cf07939b20dc"/>
    </informationRequirement>
    <literalExpression expressionLanguage="http://www.omg.org/spec/FEEL/20140401">
        <text>zip(["Item Name", "Item Price", "Item Quantity"], order.itemName, order.price, order.quantity)</text>
    </literalExpression>
</decision>
</definitions>
```

Results:

```
    order: {
        itemName: [item1, item2, item3]
        quantity: [100, 20, 300]
        price: [1000, 200, 3000]
    }
    collateOrder: [{Item Name=item1, Item Quantity=100, Item Price=1000}, {Item Name=item2, Item Quantity=20, Item Price=200}, {Item Name=item3, Item Quantity=300, Item Price=3000}]
    calculatePrice: 1004000
    determineDiscount: 25
    calculatePriceAfterDiscount: 753000.00
```

Thanks again for reporting the issue with the MID, we will investigate the issue within the Signavio extension.

Comment: Thank you so much again on investigating the issue. I was suspecting the same. Should i be creating a ticket /jira with drools team on MID issue ? Do you know where i should be reporting this issue ? Thank you again for your assistance on this.

Comment: I have created the jira to check all the aggregates, I believe for "collect"(default) MID was working as expected but I suspect we missed to cover some other aggregates. You can follow DROOLS-5392 and don't hesitate to contact us on Drools-usage mailing list https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/drools-usage if you need more generalised and iterative exchanges

Comment: Thank you. Hoping to see a patch to run my other models. Appreciate again all your efforts on this

Comment: fyi DROOLS-5392 we already are providing a pull request with the necessary code to better support the other aggregate functions, so you could checkout version `master` once that will be merged or the next Drools community version (upcoming `v7.39.0.Final`).